# c: custom shell > redirection stops working with < code that doesn't even run

Tags: c, shell, fork, io-redirection, dup2

I'm writing a custom shell for a class, and I am in the process of getting IO redirection to work. The following code is a prototype, but I'm not sure why my `>` redirection doesn't work if the code for `// deal with <` isn't commented out. The moment I keep `<` section commented out, my redirections for `>`. What am I doing wrong?

In addition, right before I `execvp` every command, I print out the command arguments. For some reason, when I input a command with `>` redirection, the arguments don't get printed out until I enter another simple command without `>` or `<`. I've tried to remove `close(fd)` and a few other things, but I'm not sure why `stdout` is closed when I try to print the command arguments.

Code where I run commands and handle `>`:

```
// runs code
void runSimple(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    int i = 0;
    int fd;

    if (pid < 0) // error
    {
        printf("An error occured while forking child for runSimple.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) // child
    {
        // loop and deal with > or <
        while (args[i])
        {
            // deal with >
            if (!strcmp(args[i], ">"))
            {
                printf("in >\n");
                fd = open(args[i + 1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
                printf("opened file: %s\n", args[i + 1]);
                if (fd < 0)
                {
                    perror("runSimple: error opening argument for >.");
                    exit(1);
                }
                dup2(fd, 1); // make child's stdout into file
                close(fd);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }
            // deal with <
            // if (!strcmp(args[i], "<"))
            // {
            //     printf("in <\n");
            //     fd = open(args[i + 1], O_RDONLY);
            //     if (fd < 0)
            //     {
            //         perror("runSimple: error opening argument for <.");
            //         exit(1);
            //     }
            //     dup2(fd, 0);
            //     close(fd);
            //     args[i] = NULL;
            // }

            i++;
        }

        // print out args before calling exec
        i = 0;
        while (args[i])
        {
            printf("cmd token: %s\n", args[i++]);
        }
        // exec input with appropriate fd
        execvp(args[0], args);
        perror("execvp");
    }
    // printf("am adult\n");
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

Comment: You just redirected stdout to a file, so all your `printf` statements will go to that file instead of your screen. You can use `fprintf( stderr, "my string: %s\n", "foo" );` to write the data to stderr instead, which hopefully still points to your terminal.

Comment: thank you! Any idea why commenting and uncommenting my code for < breaks the > code? The code for < doesn’t even run

Comment: It would segfault on the `if (!strcmp(args[i], "<"))` statements since `args[i]` is now NULL

Comment: I am so stupid, thank you! I added an extra check to see if args[i] exists first.